# How to compute the expected number of unwatched rooms?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Imagine that I have a number of rooms, `r`, that I want to have watched.  So I install one video camera in each room and have televisions that can show what's going on in a single room.

I hire `g` guards to watch the TV screens.  Each one can only watch a limited number of TV screens at the same time, so I give each one `r/g` TV screens to watch.  For example, with `r=20` and `g=4`:

```
guard_0: rooms  0- 4
guard_1: rooms  5- 9
guard_2: rooms 10-14
guard_3: rooms 15-19
```

Each guard has an independent probability of being asleep on the job, `q`. To mitigate this, I hire another set of guards to watch the same rooms.  Example:

```
guard_0_0: rooms  0- 4     guard_0_1: rooms  0- 4
guard_1_0: rooms  5- 9     guard_1_1: rooms  5- 9
guard_2_0: rooms 10-14     guard_2_1: rooms 10-14
guard_3_0: rooms 15-19     guard_3_1: rooms 15-19
```

Another possibility is to give the second set of guards a different distribution:

```
guard_0_0: rooms  0- 4     guard_0_1: rooms 0,4,8,12,16
guard_1_0: rooms  5- 9     guard_1_1: rooms 1,5,9,13,17
guard_2_0: rooms 10-14     guard_2_1: rooms 2,6,10,14,18
guard_3_0: rooms 15-19     guard_3_1: rooms 3,7,11,15,19
```

I'm trying to calculate things about the random variable `X`, the number of unwatched rooms, in these two scenarios.  My intuition is that the expected number of unwatched rooms at a given time is the same in both cases but the latter performs better because I would have less "clumping".

Is there a way to quantify this clumping?  Maybe it is the standard deviation of `X`?  And how can I calculate the average and standard deviation?

Comment: Is this just a theoretical question or is it really a question of security? From a practical standpoint I would say: If you don't want too many rooms unwatched for a longer period of time, then this problem should be solved technically. Switch the rooms being watched by each guard every minute. Since it is unlikely, that more than 2 of 8 guards are asleep at the same time, none of the rooms will be unwatched for more than 2 minutes. Also switching the rooms up might help the guards not falling asleep :)

Comment: It's actually a problem at my job but I've changed the details to make it easier to understand.  I've actually got many computers that I'm monitoring and software that monitors those computers.  The software might crash.  I can't change which program monitors which computer because they would need to coordinate among them and it would be too much overhead.

Comment: Since you seem to be in the software industry, I assume you know how to program? Your problem is not really hard to solve, but it involves a lot of case distinctions - which I'm too lazy to do by hand. But I could hook you up with an idea of a program which solves this.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case, the guards are paired off and the number of rooms is equal for each guard:  $k = r/g$ is an integer and guards $d_{ij}$ for $i = 1, 2$ watch the same rooms for each $j = 1, 2, \ldots, g$.  Then a block of $k$ rooms is unwatched if both $d_{1j}$ and $d_{2j}$ are asleep, which occurs with probability $q^2$.  The random number of unwatched rooms is therefore $X = kY$, where $Y \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(k,q^2)$ and its expected value is $\mathrm E[X] = k^2 q^2$.

The situation gets rapidly more complicated if guards do not pair off, or the number of rooms is not equal for each guard, or if the probability of being asleep is modeled as a time-dependent random variable.  In such cases, simulation would be a fast and relatively easy way to get distributional properties of $X$.

Comment: I'm okay with assuming that k is an integer.  Your solution helps me for when the guards pair off but is there anything that I can say about the second situation, where the guards are guarding different sets of rooms?  Even if it's hard to calculate, can I at least say something about which random variable has the bigger mean or bigger stddev?

Comment: Intuitively, we should naturally expect that for small $q$, the expected value of $X$ in the second scenario will be smaller than in the first scenario.  At least, this is what I *think*.  I don't have any evidence to back it up.  At this time, I don't have an explicit solution for the distribution of $X$ under the second scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure about the first scenario after I think about it.  You've assumed that the guards fall asleep together or wake up together.

Comment: I made that assumption because you specified only that the probability that a given guard is asleep is $q$.  You did not, as I alluded to in the second part of my original answer, impose any additional probability model that gives a time-dependent relationship on the state of the guard (e.g., a Markov chain model).  Therefore, the only reasonable way to proceed was to assume that the state of a guard is either *permanently* awake or asleep.